# Extracting lines appeared consecutively for 3 times or more in Linux

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, table

I have a table in Linux :

```
A 0
A 0
A 0
B 0
B 1
B 0
B 1
B 0
```

I want to extract lines appeared consecutively for 3 times or more.

My expected output is :

```
A 0
```

Actually, 3 times or more is just a simplified example. The actual situation is I want to extract lines that appear consecutively for 30 times more.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: could your input contain same lines, but in arbitrary order, like `A 0(consecutive 3 lines)..B 0 B 1 B 0 ... A 0(consecutive 3 lines again)..` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
uniq -c file | awk '$1 >= 3 { print $2,$3 }'
```

The `uniq -c` will output each line together with a count of how many times that line occurs consecutively.  For the given data, it will produce

```
   3 A 0
   1 B 0
   1 B 1
   1 B 0
   1 B 1
   1 B 0
```

The `awk` script will take this and output the last two fields if the first field is greater than or equal to 3.

The result will be

```
A 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple `awk` can be used as following.

```
awk '{!s[$0]++} END{for (x in s) if (s[x]>2) print x}' infile
```

This is printing the lines where those are repeated more than 2 times `>2` but in total. You can set `>29` to getting lines repeated ≥‎30 times.

You can use the command as follows as @Philippos pointed, to print only consecutive lines repeated ≥‎3 times.

```
awk 'p!=$0{n=0} {p=$0;n++} (n==3)'
```

Explanation: Store the previous line in `p`, count the lines in `n` and reset the counter if a line differs from the previous one. Print at the 3<sup>rd</sup> (or 30<sup>th</sup>) occurrence.

---

Or even in short approach which does the same:

```
awk 'p!=$0{n=0;p=$0} ++n==3'
```

Answer (score 1):

A pure `sed` version is missing! This will do:

```
sed 'x;G;s/\(.*\)\n\1$/+\1/;/\n/d;h;s/^+\{2\}//;/^+/d' file
```

Replace the `2` by `29` for 30 consecutive lines. I wonder whether this can be optimized somehow.

How it works: In the hold space the previous line is kept, with a leading `+` for each additional occurence. Now for each line the `x` exchanges the buffers, so the current line is in the hold space. The `G` appends the hold space, so in the pattern space we have old and new line, separated by a newline. Now if the line appears before and after the newline, we have two identical lines and the `s` command replaces one of them and the newline by a `+`. If there still is a newline in the pattern, the lines were different and we can start a new cycle (`/\n/d`). Otherwise copy the modified line to the hold space to collect the `+`. Finally remove as many `+` as lines are required (minus one). If there still is a leading `+`, we either had too many or not enough lines collected, so `d`elete.

Comment: you need this `/^+\|+$/d'` since if files has an empty line at the end it will print latest pattern-spaced line with +s sign with it : )

Answer (score 0):

With single ***awk*** script:

```
awk '{k=$1 FS $2}!a[k] || (NR==n && k==pk){ a[k]++; pk=k; n=NR+1 }
     END{ for(i in a) if(a[i] >=3) print i }' file
```

---

- `k=$1 FS $2` - crucial key, concatenation of the 1st and 2nd fields
- `!a[k] || (NR==n && k==pk)` - check if the record occurs for the first time OR it's concurrent with the previous record

---

The output:

```
A 0
```